# data from database not shown

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php and in the process of trying to convert a site from asp to php. The asp site uses ms access database and the new site will use mysql.

I am trying to produce a drop down list in a form based on distinct names from a table field. The page displayed shows the box and does not give me any error messages, but the form list is not populated, despite the fact that I know there are several qualifying names that should be there.

Here is my code:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname;", $username, $password);
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT city FROM TABLE 1 WHERE state = :state1 ORDER BY city ASC");
       $sql->execute(array(':state1' => $state1));

 echo '<form method="get" action="city.php" name="search">   ';
 echo '<input type="hidden" name="county" value="' . $state1 . '">';
 echo '<select name="city">';

foreach($sql as $row) {

    echo '<option value="'. $row['city'] . '">'. $row['city'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="go" value="Go">&nbsp;&nbsp;';
echo '</form>';

     $dbh = null;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Can anyone please tell me if there is an obvious error in my code and where I have gone wrong?

The result can be seen on the test page at: http://212.48.91.91/a1touristguide.com/ireland/county.php?county=Cavan

Many thanks in advance,

Tog Porter

Comment: What happens if you run the SQL query in phpmyadmin?  I'm not sure on the state = :state1. Is it meant to be a : or a $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you're executing the query but you're not catching the result set. Use `fetchAll()` to catch the entire result set rows as an array and loop through it, like this:

```
// your code

$sql->execute(array(':state1' => $state1));
$result = $sql->fetchAll();

echo '<form method="get" action="city.php" name="search">   ';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="county" value="' . $state1 . '">';
echo '<select name="city">';
while($row = array_shift($result)){
    echo '<option value="'. $row['city'] . '">'. $row['city'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

// your code
```

Here are the relevant references:

- [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)
- [array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Comment: Thank you so much @Rajdeep-Paul. I understand where I went wrong now and it works well :-)